# How can I get the expiry datetime of an HttpRuntime.Cache object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Is it possible to get the expiry `DateTime` of an `HttpRuntime.Cache` object?

If so, what would be the best approach?

Comment: one nasty way is to add datetime of this object in a different cache object and then subtract that lifetime with Date.Now().

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just went through the System.Web.Caching.Cache in reflector. It seems like everything that involves the expiry date is marked as internal. The only place i found public access to it, was through the Cache.Add and Cache.Insert methods.

So it looks like you are out of luck, unless you want to go through reflection, which I wouldn't recommend unless you really really need that date.

But if you wish to do it anyway, then here is some code that would do the trick:

```
private DateTime GetCacheUtcExpiryDateTime(string cacheKey)
{
    object cacheEntry = Cache.GetType().GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(Cache, new object[] { cacheKey, 1 });
    PropertyInfo utcExpiresProperty = cacheEntry.GetType().GetProperty("UtcExpires", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    DateTime utcExpiresValue = (DateTime)utcExpiresProperty.GetValue(cacheEntry, null);

    return utcExpiresValue;
}
```

[Since .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199635/cant-access-runtime-cache-using-reflection) the internal public getter of the `HttpRuntime.Cache` was replaced with a static variant and thus you will need to invoke/get the static variant:

```
object cacheEntry = Cache.GetType().GetMethod("Get").Invoke(null, new object[] { cacheKey, 1 });
```

Comment: you saved my bacon! ty for this code! i would never have thought of that because I am unfamiliar with system.reflection!

Comment: Why is it not recommend to use this method? does it load the whole cache object while looking at it?

Comment: It will be really helpful for me if you please provide steps to how to use Reflector.. I can't use this function because it gives some error..

Comment: This does not work in .NET 4.7. the internal Get method has been removed.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore, at least in .net 4.5.2. There is now a public Get method but that just returns the cached value.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by someone in comments that the accepted answer does not work in .NET 4.7

I had a lot of trouble trying to figure out what changes needs to be done to make it work in .NET 4.7

Here's my code for people using .NET 4.7

```
private DateTime GetCacheUtcExpiryDateTime(string cacheKey)
{
    var aspnetcachestoreprovider = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType().GetProperty("InternalCache", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache, null);
    var intenralcachestore = aspnetcachestoreprovider.GetType().GetField("_cacheInternal", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(aspnetcachestoreprovider);
    Type TEnumCacheGetOptions = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(d => d.Name == "CacheGetOptions").FirstOrDefault();
    object cacheEntry = intenralcachestore.GetType().GetMethod("DoGet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, new[] { typeof(bool), typeof(string), TEnumCacheGetOptions }, null).Invoke(intenralcachestore, new Object[] { true, cacheKey, 1 }); ;
    PropertyInfo utcExpiresProperty = cacheEntry.GetType().GetProperty("UtcExpires", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    DateTime utcExpiresValue = (DateTime)utcExpiresProperty.GetValue(cacheEntry, null);

    return utcExpiresValue;
}
```

And for those who wants the code to function in multiple different environments (sandbox using .NET 4.5 and production using .NET 4.7), here's some patch work:

```
private DateTime GetCacheUtcExpiryDateTime(string cacheKey)
{
    MethodInfo GetCacheEntryMethod = null;
    Object CacheStore = null;
    bool GetterFound = true;

    GetCacheEntryMethod = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType().GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (GetCacheEntryMethod != null)
    {
        GetterFound = true;
        CacheStore = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache;
    }
    else
    {
        var aspnetcachestoreprovider = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType().GetProperty("InternalCache", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache, null);
        var intenralcachestore = aspnetcachestoreprovider.GetType().GetField("_cacheInternal", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(aspnetcachestoreprovider);
        Type TEnumCacheGetOptions = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(d => d.Name == "CacheGetOptions").FirstOrDefault();
        GetCacheEntryMethod = intenralcachestore.GetType().GetMethod("DoGet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, new[] { typeof(bool), typeof(string), TEnumCacheGetOptions }, null);
        GetterFound = false;
        CacheStore = intenralcachestore;
    }

    dynamic cacheEntry;
    if (GetterFound)
        cacheEntry = GetCacheEntryMethod.Invoke(CacheStore, new Object[] { cacheKey, 1 });
    else
        cacheEntry = GetCacheEntryMethod.Invoke(CacheStore, new Object[] { true, cacheKey, 1 });

    PropertyInfo utcExpiresProperty = cacheEntry.GetType().GetProperty("UtcExpires", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    DateTime utcExpiresValue = (DateTime)utcExpiresProperty.GetValue(cacheEntry, null);

    return utcExpiresValue;
}
```

Comment: could you please share, how to get CacheItemPriority?, same like  expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

For my solution, I stored the expiry value in the the value of cached object and used the same value as expiry for the cache.

```
var expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("key", new { Value = "Value", Expiry = expiry }, null, expiry, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

And when you need to check the expiry you can get the object's Expiry property

```
dynamic cachedData = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("key");
DateTime cacheExpiry = cachedData.Expiry;
```