# Get cache's expiration time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

Is it possible to get the expiration time of a specific cache? I was hoping to find something like this:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache(key).ExpireTime
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/350374/309973

Answer (score 2):

Just for sake of ease if people hit this post, this works very well:

```
    private DateTime GetCacheUtcExpiryDateTime(string cacheKey)
    {
        object cacheEntry = Cache.GetType().GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(Cache, new object[] { cacheKey, 1 });
        PropertyInfo utcExpiresProperty = cacheEntry.GetType().GetProperty("UtcExpires", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        DateTime utcExpiresValue = (DateTime)utcExpiresProperty.GetValue(cacheEntry, null);

        return utcExpiresValue;
    }
```

Original answer found here [How can I get the expiry datetime of an HttpRuntime.Cache object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344479/how-can-i-get-the-expiry-datetime-of-an-httpruntime-cache-object)

Mind you, this uses reflection. Works very well though and provides you with a nice UTC date in the `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format.