# Can't Access Runtime Cache Using Reflection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, reflection

I am trying to get the expiry date of a `HttpRuntime.Cache` object, as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/350374/1778169

The method is:

```
private DateTime GetCacheUtcExpiryDateTime(string cacheKey)
{
    object cacheEntry = Cache.GetType().GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(Cache, new object[] { cacheKey, 1 });
    PropertyInfo utcExpiresProperty = cacheEntry.GetType().GetProperty("UtcExpires", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    DateTime utcExpiresValue = (DateTime)utcExpiresProperty.GetValue(cacheEntry, null);    
    return utcExpiresValue;
}
```

When I try to use the above method, the first line won't compile:

> An object reference is required for object.GetType()

If I replace `Cache.GetType()` with `HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType()` it compiles, but I get null returned from this part:

`cacheType.GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using .NET 4.5. System.Web.Caching is version 4.0.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have looked up the original source using the [website](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) Microsoft setup in order to find out more details of the `HttpRuntime` class, specifically the `Cache` property. If you look at [line 2794 of the System.Web.HttpRuntime class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpRuntime.cs,2794) you can see the following definition of the `Cache` property:

```
 public static Cache Cache {
        get {
              ...
        }
 }
```

Now since the property is `static` you cannot use the binding flags you are using, since right now you are looking for a `NonPublic` member that belongs to an `Instance`. In .NET static variables don't belong to an instance, therefor the code you posted will result in an exception being thrown; it simply cannot find the member you are looking for, since it not exists on the instance you provided -- it does however exists on the type definition of the class you are looking into (`HttpRuntime`).

In order to make your code work you will need to omit the binding flags, the internal .NET code that handles your request will now understand we are trying to lookup a static method: `HttpRuntime.Cache.GetType().GetMethod("Get")`. Note: if you want to have bindingflags (readability, understandabilty), you could add: `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static`, which exactly does the same as whenever you omit the flags.

If you want to execute the method and get the result (get the actual `Cache`) you can invoke the `MethodDefinition` you just received from the `GetMethod` using `Invoke(null, null)`.

Comment: Thank you. That is such a clear and informative answer, I really appreciate it.  But now I don't understand why that other answer worked for so many people!

Comment: That question was asked in 2008 and answered in 2014, thus they were using older .NET framework versions. Probably because in a later .NET version (my guess would be > 4.5) they removed the publicly (instanced) Getter and replaced it with the static variant. I'll update the answer you've linked to so that other users will not get stuck on this problem!

Comment: I got the impression that this was applicable to 4.5 and the 'breaking change' was 4.7.... obviously I'm wrong.  Thanks again Jevgeni :)